# Do I use Hibernate with Hikari correctly?

Tags: java, hibernate, hikaricp

it's my first time I'm using hibernate so I've got a little question.
Is this way of using hibernate 5.1 with hikariCP 2.4.3 correct?

I'm not sure if the pooling is working like this.

should I call

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

or

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

to get a session?
when i call

```
session.close();
```

is the connection closed or given back to the pool.

the HibernateDataStore is used by threads for accessing the db

thanks for help

**The Config**

```
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">
            org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName">
            com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost/xyz
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user">user</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password">xyz</property>

        <property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize">100</property>

        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">
            org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext
        </property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping class="XYZ"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**My DataStore-Class**

```
public class HibernateDataStore implements DataStore {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    /** factory for hibernate sessions */
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        setUpHibernate();
    }

    /**
     * set up the hibernate session-factory
     */
    private static void setUpHibernate() {
        logger.debug("building session factory");
        final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure( "config/server/hibernate.cfg.xml" )
                .build();
        try {
            sessionFactory = new MetadataSources( registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("problems building hibernate sessionFactory " + e.getMessage());

            // The registry would be destroyed by the SessionFactory, but we had trouble building the SessionFactory
            // so destroy it manually.
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy( registry );
        }
        logger.debug("finished building session factory");
    }


    @Override
    public void storeProduct(Product product) {
        logger.info("storing product: " + product.getTitle());
        Instant start = Instant.now();

        final Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        //final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save( product );
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

        Instant stop = Instant.now();
        logger.debug("product saved (took " + Duration.between(start, stop).toMillis() + "ms)");
    }
}
```

Comment: Native Hibernate, not JPA? No other framework to help you out?

Comment: i'm not using jpa because i've read it has some limitations and i don't want to waist time on that

Comment: You should use Spring or Java EE to help you with the bootstrap part. JPA is the way to go, and for the "limitation" part you can use Hibernate from JPA too.

Comment: I'm not building a new project. I can't use spring or java ee. I'll try converting dataStore to JPA

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Spring to handle session factory

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
</bean>

<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
    <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="dataSourceClassName"
        value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" />
    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xyz</prop>
            <prop key="user">root</prop>
            <prop key="password"></prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.xyz.model" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> -->
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.minimumIdle">5</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.maximumPoolSize">20</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.idleTimeout">30000</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
</bean>
```